# Removing Numbers from Column that Don't Appear in Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Took a large data set, removed any numbers that are not within 2 SD from a specific column and created an array, now I want to remove any numbers not in array from columns without messing up index. Would preferably like to convert any non-present numbers as nan.

Code used to remove values outside of 2 SD:

```py
pupil_area_array = numpy.array(part_data['pupil_area'])

mean = numpy.mean(part_data['pupil_area'], axis=0)
sd = numpy.std(part_data['pupil_area'], axis=0)

final_list = [x for x in part_data['pupil_area'] if (x > mean - 2 * sd)]
final_list = [x for x in final_list if (x < mean + 2 * sd)]
print(final_list)
```

Comment: Don't think you will be able to produce the result using a generator. But you may be able to use `map()` https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not restricted to using a generator, you should be able to use **`map()`** https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-map-function/:

```py
def filter_sd(value):
  if x > mean - 2 * sd:
    return x
  return None #or return 'Nan'

final = map(filter_sd, part_data['pupil_area'])
```